# PHP Serialize & Unserialize

Tags: php

I have problem with Unserialize which return nothing after getting it from $_POST. I post a simple array from a form and I could see double quotes been added to the serialized string. I tried stripslashes before serialzing and before unserializing, but the result is the same with no output. I have turned of magic_quotes_gpc in php.ini and again no luck. When I hardcode the values in unserialize by adding "\" manually gave me the desired string, So I tried with addslashes and again left with nothing. Please help me resolve this.

```
<?php


$tmp = $_POST["strVid"];

$myNewArray = unserialize($trp);
print_r($myNewArray);

$myArray = array('key1'=>'value1', 'key2'=>'value2');
$serialized = serialize($myArray);
?>

<form  onsubmit="return validate(this)" action="test_serialize.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="strVid1" value="this is mega shit"/>
<input type="hidden" name="strVid" value="<?php echo $serialized; ?>">
<input type="Submit" name="next" value="Next"/>

</form>
```

Updated...

After Serialize: a:2:{s:4:"key1";s:6:"value1";s:4:"key2";s:6:"value2";}

After stripslashes of Serialize: a:2:{s:4:"key1";s:6:"value1";s:4:"key2";s:6:"value2";}

when I add \ manually

$myNewArray = unserialize("a:2:{s:4:\"key1\";s:6:\"value1\";s:4:\"key2\";s:6:\"value2\";} ");

I get the output as Array ( [key1] => value1 [key2] => value2 )

Thanks

Comment: unserialize($trp); ? maybe unserialize($tmp); ? Or just a copy past mistake ?

Comment: Are you sure the double quotes are being added to the serialized string and not earlier in the process to `$_POST`?  If you could post output at each step (what is being sent, `$_POST['whatever']`, `serialize(...)`, `unserialize(...)`, etc. that would help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code:

```
<input type="hidden" name="strVid" value="<?php echo $serialized; ?>">
```

That's most certainly wrong, because the variable will contain double quotes; you must escape those:

```
<input type="hidden" name="strVid" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($serialized, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>">
```

Btw, this is assuming you're doing this to unserialize it:

```
$myNewArray = unserialize($_POST["strVid"]);
```

Comment: Thanks Jack that did the trick and am relieved. I am new to php and just started learning things on my own. And almost all my learning is thru this forum and previously answered questions here. Really appreciate the help guys.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a typo?

```
$tmp = $_POST["strVid"];

$myNewArray = unserialize($trp);
```

`$trp` != `$tmp`

Comment: Jakub & Kakawait It's a type because I have tried little too many things and was bit furious..

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using urlencode on the serialized input?

http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php